# Ability to use variable in bash SED

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I'm trying to use sed to add a variable prefix to my command...

```
datestamp="$(date +'%D %r %Z')"
prefix=$("$datestamp site=$i space=$number")

prefix=$("site=$i space=$number")
echo test this thing | sed 's/^/$prefix /'
```

I'm expecting
site=abc space=12 test this thing

Comment: Could you please post variables values samples too in your post?

Comment: See: [Difference between single and double quotes in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/3776858)

Comment: You should change your `prefix` variable to `prefix="$datestamp site=$i space=$number"` once and try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply replace the single quotes for the sed line with double quotes, and that should do the trick.

```
datestamp="$(date +'%D %r %Z')"
prefix="$datestamp site=$i space=$number"
echo test this thing | sed "s@^@$prefix @"
```

Comment: I get this error line 28: 11/03/18 03:28:02 PM EDT site=name.thing space=thisisit: No such file or directory

Comment: lol well I don't want to run it ! - do I need to echo it or something?

Comment: `prefix="$datestamp site=$i space=$number")`